# Using Azure Resource Graph to get other user's Resources

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

I am trying to query with an app ID all the resources a user has. My current implementation is to get all the resources my app has access to, and then query the RBAC of each one of those resources to see if the user has access. It seems to be way too many calls for something it can be done for my current user using Azure Resource Graph. Is there a way to use Azure Resource Graph but specify which user I want to get the resources for (assuming my app has reader access to all resources in the tenant)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, want you need to find is the role assignments in your subscription, its resource type is `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments`, which is not included in the Azure Resource Graph.

Your option is to use the REST API - [`Role Assignments - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/list), filter with the `ObjectId` of the user in Azure AD. To get the access token to call the REST API with the AD App(the AppId you mentioned), you need to use the client credential flow, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#client-credentials-grant-non-interactive-clients).

**Sample**:

Check the `scope` in the response, they are the resources the user can access.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?$filter=principalId eq '<object-id>'&api-version=2018-09-01-preview
```

[image]